# is there any way to listen change detection completed event in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, optimization, angular-changedetection

I have a component that contains an iframe, but only visible (`*ngif`) after the `http` call.

```
<iframe id="myFrame" [src]="url | sanitizeUrl" *ngIf="showIFrame "></iframe>
```

Here is the `getData` method that enables the `showIFrame` property.

```
this.getData().subscribe(
  (_response: string) => {
     this.showIFrame = true;
     setTimeout(() => {
         this._listenClickOnIframe();
     }, 100);
});
```

based on `showIFrame` iframe is visible.

I have one other method `_listenClickOnIframe` that add `onclick` event to `iFrame`. This method is inside `setTimeout` with `100ms` wait. If I don't use `setTimeout` the `_listenClickOnIframe` method gets executed before DOM changes and there is no iFrame on DOM.

Is there any other way to handle this? For some slow machines `100ms` (random number of miliseconds) may not be enough, and which I think not a good approach.

I am looking kind of change detection completed event, is there any way or better approach to solve such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen to the `load` event of the iframe and only start listening then:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" [src]="url | sanitizeUrl" *ngIf="showIFrame" (load)="_listenClickOnIframe()"></iframe>
```

LE:

For general angular lifecycle practices I recommend reading the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks .

The last hook which is called (after rendering) is ngAfterViewChecked but maybe you don't necessarily need this one (using it might affect the performance of your app as it is called pretty often).

Here is another link explaining different hooks and their uses: https://guide.freecodecamp.org/angular/lifecycle-hooks/

Comment: thanks! great help? but there could be other scenarios, where one needs event after change detection completed, any help on that??

Comment: @SunilGarg usually you can see here the order in which angular lifecycle hooks are called: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks . The last event for changeDetection is ngAfterViewChecked but maybe you don't need this one exactly, you can check there how/when other events are called (check my edited post)